# Validate.js ReGex not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex, validate.js

I'm attempting to use the format: pattern: functionality of Validate.js to make sure a password meets the requirements of at least one upper case, one lower case, one number, and one special character, with a minimum length of 8 and a max of 20. The presence and length function as intended. Anyone got any tips?

```
 password: {
    presence: {
      allowEmpty: false,
      message: "is required",
      admin: "required",
      label: "Password*",
    },
    length: {
      minimum: 8,
      message: "must be at least 8 characters",
      maximum: 20,
    },
    format: {
      pattern: /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!|@|#|\$|%|\^|&|\*])(?=.{8,20})/,
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```js
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*]).{8,20}$/
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [!@#$%^&*]               any character of: '!', '@', '#', '$',
                             '%', '^', '&', '*'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .{8,20}                  any character except \n (between 8 and 20
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```